# How to fix InvalidOperationException: Cannot work with Freezable System.Windows.Shell.WindowChrome in threads, because they can´t be freezed

Tags: c#, wpf

We currently working for automatical weighing system. Using C#, .NET, MVVM, WPF and XAML. When we start application, we log in and then menu show with some agendas and modules. I got a new computer in company, so I installed few things and Visual Studio 2019. I had 2015 version on my old pc. Installation was succesfull. Problem is, when I click on some agenda or modul in the menu.

Sometimes it opens correctly, but often it end on

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot work with Freezable System.Windows.Shell.WindowChrome in threads, because it cannot be freezed.

That exception happend in xaml.cs, in this piece of code:

```
public DWTimeWindowDetail()
{
    InitializeComponent(); - here is a exception
}
```

Maybe there is a problem in Visual Studio 2019, because in 2015 it never happend.

Comment: Is it "treads" or "threads"?

Comment: @UweKeim Threads. My mistake.

Comment: @UweKeim It is perhaps the same, but it also not. I tried the solution they write in answers, but it didn´t help. :/

Comment: @UweKeim Or wait a second ... It seems it working now. I tried open same agenda 5 times in a row and no exception happend, since I edited style like in that duplicate thread answers.